# Replace string in xml document

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

How to write an xpath expression for :

```
 <script src="../../Scripts/ex.js"></script>
```

which will match the src value (`../../Scripts/ex.js`). Because i want to relace `../../Scripts` with some other string.

Comment: Do you want to add "version" of js file?

Comment: i just want to select all script tags and replace there src values

Answer (score 2):

you can go with the following code.

```
 TextReader tr = new StringReader(response);
    XElement xelement = XElement.Load(tr);
    var Script = xelement.Descendants("script").ToList();
    if (Script.Count() > 0)
    {
     Script.First().Attribute("src").Value = "../../Scripts/NewEXWithReplace.js";

    }
```

Comment: You replace one `string` with another, not the src of `script`

Comment: this way will not replace `src` in source document, result will be only new string instance, I assume that OP wants to replace this `src` in actual document not to obtain modified string.

Comment: Now you replace only the first `script` but I think that you should chage only scripts that has `../../Scripts/ex.js` in the `src` attribute also I think it should be done for all occurrences...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use HtmlAgilityPack which allows you to access attributes usefully [codeplex tool](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(@"<script src="../../Scripts/ex.js"></script>" />");

foreach (var script in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("script"))
{

    script.Attributes["src"].Value = "loading.gif";
}
```

Another way is to use linq to xml

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to XML

```
var xdocument = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml"); // you can use Parse or whatever
var elements = xdocument.XPathSelectElements("//script[@src='../../Scripts/ex.js']");
foreach (var element in elements)
{
  element.Attribute("src").SetValue("foo");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you wanted an XPath expression, but what about a simple string replace?

e.g.

```
string s = "<script src=\"../../Scripts/ex.js\"></script>";
string newS = s.Replace("../../Scripts", "../../Scripts2"); // Or whatever you want to replace it with
```

Comment: OP wants to replace *xxxxx* string from the *XML* document.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but the XML document in question looks like an ASP.NET (or Razor) page. I'm just presenting a different way of solving the problem!